# Get all documents and project timestamp from ObjectId in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have not managed to figure out how I can project a list of fields and include the date created (timestamp) generated from the objectid.

I'm using MongoDB 4.0.10 and I know I can do this:

```
> ObjectId("5a682326bf8380e6e6584ba5").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2018-01-24T06:09:42Z")
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this:

```
db.users.find(
   { status: "active" },
   { "ObjectId(_id).getTimestamp()": 1 }
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) operator

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { "status": "active" } },
    { $project: { ts: { $toDate: "$_id" } }} 
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sHHZV8NmVSe)

Comment: Note that this requires Mongo 4.0